# how to make loading page while preparing data to be presented in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

i have simple textfield and image view in one view controller, this page will be used to update the user information, the data in the textfield will be available immediately, but for the avatar, it takes some time, so the image will be appear  around 3 second after the page open.

I want to make the page fully open only after the avatar is completely downloaded. so i want an activity indicator in a loading page first, after the download is complete then the page open. I mean, like when we open our Mac, there is an activity indicator first before all the data is presented

how do i do that ? do i need to add another view controller? or is is there any UI element to support this ? I have tried using activity indicator, the activity indicator runs but the image is still not available. here is the simplified code i use

Thanks :)

```
import UIKit

class EditInfoVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstnameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastnameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var avatar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // round corner
        saveButton.layer.cornerRadius = saveButton.bounds.width/4.5
        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = avatar.bounds.width/2
        avatar.layer.masksToBounds = true

        //Give title to navigation controller
        self.navigationItem.title = "Update Profile"



        // disable save button in the beginning
        saveButton.isEnabled = false
        saveButton.alpha = 0.4


        //shortcut
        let username = userInfo?["username"] as! String
        let email = userInfo?["email"] as! String
        let avatarPath = userInfo?["avatar"] as! String

        let fullname = userInfo?["fullname"] as! String
        let fullnameArray = fullname.characters.split {$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        let firstname = fullnameArray[0]
        let lastname = fullnameArray[1]

        // assign variable sebagai nilai awal
        usernameTextfield.text = username
        firstnameTextfield.text = firstname
        lastnameTextfield.text = lastname
        emailTextField.text = email


        if !(avatarPath.isEmpty) {

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            let imageURL = URL(string: avatarPath)
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: imageURL!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if let imageData = data {
                        self.avatar.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }

            })

            task.resume()
        }




    }




    @IBAction func saveButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

// send data to database




    }







}




}
```

Comment: use MBProgressHUD library to show spinner with animation and text

Answer (score 2):

It's best to present a `ViewController` that shows some form of loading symbol, either a spinner or progress bar.
To make things simpler, you could add a `UIView` (with a loading indicator) on top of this ViewController while the data is being fetched. Once everything is loaded simply remove that `UIView`.

Also, from a UX standpoint it's better to have [skeleton screens](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-speed-up-your-ux-with-skeleton-screens/) than loading bars/spinners.